# Postgresql, how to import large bak.gz file?

Tags: command-line, postgresql

I have 13GB bak.gz database dump. How can I import it to my local pgsql db by ubuntu command line?

Answer (score 1):

If the dump was made with [`pg_dumpall`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html), it can typically be played with :

```
gzip -dc filename.bak.gz | psql -U postgres
```

Note that the default security settings set in `pg_hba.conf` require this to be run by the `postgresql` administrative user (use `sudo`).

If it's the dump of a single database, it might have been made with [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) with the custom format (`-Fc`) in which case it has to be fed to [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html). To be sure, the file must be gunzip'ed and the start of the contents inspected.